# How to modify or delete a saved Windows network password?

Tags: windows-7, networking, passwords

I usually go to Network->House-PC and can then access my Office-PC but I changed the password on my Office PC and now I get "Cannot connect to Office-PC" error. How can I provide it with the new credentials to be able to log in again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Manage Windows Stored User Names and Password for Networks

1. Push Windows Key + R
2. Type: `control keymgr.dll`
3. Hit **OK**
4. Select the that needs to be deleted
5. Click **Remove**
6. Click **Close**
7. Try again

Comment: It's has been a while but I believe this is were it's saved. Couldn't confirm at the moment bc I'm at work using my iPhone to answer this question.

Comment: It's also available from Control Panel - Users - Manage Credentials